# Python get latest directory and unzip

Tags: python

I'm writing a python script that is compressed. I managed to extract the file and within one of the sub directories there are more compressed files. I want my script to find the newest compressed file available and extract it.

I broke my scripts into different sections for troubleshooting. Below is the second section that contains the part I'm having trouble with:

```
import os
import time
import glob

path = "/home/user/scripts/logs/old" #logs was the original compressed file. Old is
#where the other compressed files are.

for file in glob.glob( os.path.join(path, '*.tar.gz') ):
    filename = os.path.basename(file)
    statinfo = os.stat(file)
    print file + "  " + time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file))
```

The script just lists the file name and then the timestamp the compressed files were last modified. How do I tell python to get the name of the last modified file so I can continue with extracting it?

Comment: What do you mean by "the last modified file"? A file that was modified since you last looked (so you'd have to keep track of the "last-looked-time")? Or the most recently changed file out of a list of files (which, if nothing changes between runs of the script, may be the same file several times)? In the latter case, collect the timestamps and sort by them.

Comment: @Evert - The most recently changed file. Script after running should delete the files therefore should never see the same file again. If I do get the timestamps and sort, how do I go back to correlating the name and times together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've got the file list (by whatever means, e.g. globbing) in a variable named `files_to_check`, just use [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) with `os.path.getmtime` as the key:

```
files_to_check = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.tar.gz'))
most_recent_file = max(files_to_check, key=os.path.getmtime)
```

Comment: Good answer, elegant use of key parameter!

Comment: Agreed! This is elegant its stupid simple! Too bad I spent 3 days trying to figure it out! Thanks @ShadowRanger

Comment: @user3808507: for completeness: call`shutil.unpack_archive(most_recent_file)`, to unzip.